# C# Interface overload implementation

Tags: c#, interface, overloading

I have an interface with overloaded methods.

```
interface ISide
{
    Dictionary<string, decimal> Side(string side1, decimal cost1);
    Dictionary<string, decimal> Side(string side1, decimal cost1, string side2, decimal cost2);
}
```

I would like to implement only one of these depending on which class is inheriting it, but I am getting a compiler error by attempting to implement only one of these methods per class.

```
class Entree: ISide
{
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> Side(string side1, decimal cost1, string side2, decimal cost2);
}
```

In this situation, do I have to use optional parameters to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Mind sharing a bit more info about the context here? It could help giving you best advice. :)

Comment: Edit the question and use the actual interface names. That will make your code's context a tad more obvious to anyone reading your post. :)

Comment: Edited to show implementation.

Comment: Dictionary<string, decimal> Side(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, decimal>>sideCost);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should turn the concept of  `string side1, decimal cost1` into an object.

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Cost {get; set;}
}
```

Then your interface takes a list of `MenuItem`

```
interface ISide
{
    Dictionary<string, decimal> Side(IEnumerable<MenuItem> sides);
}
```

Now, this being said.  It seems weird to me that `Entree` is an `ISide`.  You should try to be a little more specific about what that interface means (maybe `IComeWithSides` or something)

Comment: The actual implementation is adding sides to a dish. We know that entrees generally come with two sides, but sandwiches usually only come with one. Other dishes come with no sides(in which case, the interface is not inherited.) Splitting that up would seem frivolous, no?

Comment: Then your interface should take in a collection object as the parameter.

Comment: I tend to agree, although it would be much easier if OP gave more details on the context. It's kinda hard to give good advice over `ISomething` :p

Comment: The problem I have with showing my version is that as a user carousing google for help, it is incredibly difficult for me to weed through people's everyday use of their own code to find an answer to a specific question. So, while I agree that it would probably be more helpful for commenters to give me specific situational advice, its almost like not reusing code, when maybe we should be. Therefore, I generally try to make my post as helpful to as many people as I possibly can.

Comment: But the solution to your "problem" changed completely when you gave more context.  The original answer was completely unrelated because we didn't know the context.

Comment: @Justin Your question has completely changed!!! Hard to see how this is the answer to the question you originally asked. It may very well be the solution to your problem. Sigh.

Comment: Just to add to @Caleb advice: your interface should *not* use dictionaries as public members. Create an additional class that will represent what the `Side` method is supposed to return.

Answer (score 7):

```
interface ISomething1
{
    int SomeMethod(int someInt1);
    }

interface ISomething2
{
    int SomeMethod(int someInt1, int someInt2);
}

class Someclass1 : ISomething1
{
    public int SomeMethod(int someInt1);
}

class Someclass2 : ISomething2
{
    int SomeMethod(int someInt1, int someInt2);
}

class Someclass3 : ISomething1, ISomething2 
{
    public int SomeMethod(int someInt1);
    int SomeMethod(int someInt1, int someInt2);
}
```

Comment: This is a correct answer given the context of the original question.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it like that.You have to implement all methods defined in your interface.But instead you can use `params` keyword if only your parameter count changes.

```
interface ISomething
{
    int SomeMethod(params int[] numbers);
}
```

If you want to require at least one parameter then you can do the following:

```
 int SomeMethod(int x, params int[] numbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to implement an interface you have to implement **all** methods. Either do that, or use a single method with an optional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When a class implements an interfaces, you must implement all the methods from the interface. If you want to implement only a few methods use an abstract class.

Comment: Even the abstract class must implement the interface in full. Using an abstract class in this case doesn't really resolve anything, in my opinion. :)

Comment: The point that I was trying to make was that he may use an abstract class instead of an interface :)